# LDAP over SSL using Wordpress plugin

Tags: ssl, ldap

I'm trying to integrate LDAP over SSL on a Wordpress site using the plugin here:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/active-directory-integration/

The site is hosted on MediaTemple and out Active Directory server is hosted locally behind our firewall.

I successfully tested the connection using LDAP over SSL outside of my firewall - so I think the issue resides somewhere on the MediaTemple server.

Using plugin version 1.1.4 with WP 3.7.1

note: my site is not an adult site, I just replaced the real site with x's :)

[INFO] method authenticate() called
[INFO] ------------------------------------------
PHP version: 5.4.13
WP version: 3.7.1
ADI version: 1.1.4
OS Info : Linux xxxxxxxxxx.com 2.6.32-042stab083.2 #1 SMP Fri Nov 8 18:08:40 MSK 2013 x86_64 
Web Server : cgi-fcgi
adLDAP ver.: 3.3.2 Extended (201104081456)
------------------------------------------
[NOTICE] username: murphyd
[NOTICE] password: **not shown**
[INFO] Options for adLDAP connection:
- account_suffix:
- base_dn: cn=users,dc=xxxxxxxxx,dc=local
- domain_controllers: ldaps://firewall.xxxxxxxx.com
- ad_port: 636
- use_tls: 0
- network timeout: 5
[NOTICE] adLDAP object created.
[INFO] max_login_attempts: 50
[INFO] users failed logins: 0
[NOTICE] trying account suffix ""
[ERROR] Authentication failed
[WARN] storing failed login for user "murphyd"

Any suggestions?

Comment: If authorization is happening over SSL, you'll want to enable TLS (Transport Layer Security) on the Media Temple server.

Comment: X3074861X - If enabling TLS, the plugin notes to use port 389. I have my port on AD set to 636 so I have to use SSL and disable TSL. Right?

Comment: Apart from installing the SSL cert, are there other server modifications needed to make this work? LDAP in enabled in the PHP info.

Comment: Yes you're correct, I read your configuration wrong. Are you using a self-signed certificate?

Comment: X3074861X - No, I am using a 3rd party SSL and the SSL has been verified on the site. That same ssl key has been set up on the Active Directory side. I think the main problem is that I have no idea how Active Directory administrator set his side up and I (the web developer) think we need to get together and follow the instructions documented for my server Centos as documented here: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/CDS/ag/8.0/Managing_SSL-Configuring_LDAP_Clients_to_Use_SSL.html